# What type of represantation is default in python to store Unicode strings?

Tags: python, unicode

If I do this in python:

```
>>> name = "âțâîâ"
>>> name
'\xc3\xa2\xc8\x9b\xc3\xa2\xc3\xae\xc3\xa2'
>>> len(name)
10
>>> u = name.decode('utf-8')
>>> len (u)
5
>>>
```

What is the default encoding in python if you don't specify any ?

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Please, there is **no such thing** as "unicode encoding". There's Unicode, and there's encoding. Unicode is **not** an encoding.

Comment: @DanielRoseman just Google: "unicode encoding", also my dictionary says: U·ni·code Noun /ˈyo͞oniˌkōd/ 
An international encoding standard for use with different languages and scripts, by which each letter, digit, or symbol is assigned a unique numeric value that applies across different platforms and programs

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: There is an enormous amount of confusion surrounding Unicode; I'm not surprised a dictionary gets it wrong too..

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: From Wikipedia: [Unicode is a computing industry standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). It happens to specify some encodings (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32), but Unicode is *far more* than 'an encoding standard'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not saying that Daniel is wrong I edited my post accordingly,  I am just saying when an error has so much coverage I could be pardoned for annoying someone(see sentence start with „Please”)

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: I am not saying you said Daniel is wrong. :-P I am merely providing you another angle to help clarify that Unicode is not an encoding. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters So if I add `u = u"âțâîâ"` it gets to `u'\xe2\u021b\xe2\xee\xe2'` which seems is not any of the UTFs so python uses his own encoding for keeping Unicode strings internally?

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu: You are seeing a python unicode literal, which uses `\uFFFF` and `\xFF` escapes to *display* a unicode value to you. That has nothing to do with the internal encoding, and everything with trying to work in all situations. Try `print u` instead, and compare that to `print repr(u)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using Python 2. (If not, this answer is bad.)

What happens is the following:

```
>>> name = "âțâîâ"
```

You assign to `name` a (byte) string whose contents is determined by your encoding of the terminal resp. of your text editor. In your case, this is obviously UTF8.

These bytes are shown with

```
>>> name
'\xc3\xa2\xc8\x9b\xc3\xa2\xc3\xae\xc3\xa2'
```

Only if you decode it with

```
>>> u = name.decode('utf-8')
```

you get a unicode string. Here you specify that encoding.

A simpler and more reliably way would be to directly do

```
u = u"âțâîâ"
```

and only then extract the bytes according to your wanted encoding:

```
name = u.encode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying a python string literal, and their encoding is determined by the default settings of your editor (or in the case of the python interpreter, of your terminal). Python did not have a say in this.

By default, python 2 tries to interpret source code as ASCII. In python 3 this has been switched to UTF-8.

Please read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) to further understand the difference between Unicode and input and output encodings. You really also should read Joel Spolksy's [article on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).